# Website with unique homepage layout in Django Templates

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I am building a website with a unique homepage design (homepage has a different header and logo arrangement than all the other pages). However, I would like to have a base template which everything inherits from, to cut down on redundancies.

```
-base.html
  -basehome.html (inherits from base.html)
  -basesecond.html (inherits from base.html)
    -about.html (inherits from basesecond.html)
    -etc...
```

So base.html holds the html declaration and the structure. Basehome.html and basesecond.html contain the different header structures and the various other pages on the site inherit from basesecond.html.

So the problem I keep running into is, it seems like I need to put a block within a block to handle the body content which is obviously contained the (furthest) child template. As far as I know, Django does not let you do this.

base.html--

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Mysite</title>
     </head>
    <body id="{% block bodyholder %}{% endblock %}">
        <div id="hd">{# start of hd #}
            {% block hd %}{% endblock %}
        </div>{# end of the hd #}
        <div id="bd">{# start of body #}
            {% block bd %}{% endblock %}
        </div>{# end of body #}             
    </body>
</html>
```

basehome.html--

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block bodyholder %}bodyhome{% endblock %}

{% block hd %}
    big logo and wide header
{% endblock %}

{% block bd %}
    homepage body content
    this part works just like I want it to.
{% endblock %}
```

basesecond.html--

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block bodyholder %}bodysecond{% endblock %}

{% block hd %}
    small logo and narrow header
{% endblock %}

{% block bd %}
    second page body content
    here is where I want to put extra blocks like
    {% block unique about page sidebar %}{% endblock %}
    but it breaks the template system
{% endblock %}
```

What is the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: What problem? This works exactly as you describe.

Comment: Indeed, there isn't any problem nesting blocks like this in Django templates.  Are you getting an error?

Comment: One thing to keep in mind with Django templates is that a block contained in a child template can *override* or *extend* a block in a parent template. On occasion, I've put in blocks in a child template that are empty to override a parent block to eliminate having to add code on every child template. The template system is pretty flexible. I think you can probably put your sidebar block in the parent template and only fill it on your "about" page without any issues.

Comment: Guys, thanks for all the input. What is the S.O. way of admitting you made a dumb mistake in your question? It looks like I was re-using a block name twice. I was getting TemplateSyntaxError.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using exactly what you have shown you need to re-write a small portion:

instead of this

```
{% block unique about page sidebar %}{% endblock %}
```

replace it with this

```
{% block unique %}{% endblock %}
{% block about %}{% endblock %}
{% block page %}{% endblock %}
{% block sidebar %}{% endblock %}
```

Otherwise, everything looks like it should work.  What error codes or behavior are you seeing that you aren't expecting?